# Script doesn't work after combining 2 different scripts in one blade.php file (laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel

I wanted to combine 2 script from different sources into one blade.php file in laravel as some contents need to use different script respectively. The 2 scripts are like this:

1st script:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
                </script>
```

2nd script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    $('.itemName').select2({
                    placeholder: 'Select state',
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/select2-autocomplete-ajax',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        delay: 250,
                        processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text: item.name,
                                    id: item.id
                                }
                            })
                        };
                        },
                        cache: true
                    }
                    });


                </script>
```

This is how I combined above scripts. Simply just copy the 2nd script at below of the first script:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
                <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
                <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
                </script>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $('.itemName').select2({
                    placeholder: 'Select state',
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/select2-autocomplete-ajax',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        delay: 250,
                        processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    text: item.name,
                                    id: item.id
                                }
                            })
                        };
                        },
                        cache: true
                    }
                    });


                </script>
```

However, when I compiled, it doesn't worked as I expected because one of the scripts doesn't function.
How should I compile two scripts in one file?

Comment: `one of the scripts doesn't function` - which one? and any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Supposedly got 'Select state'  text in the dropdown box, but there's no, and the dropdown cannot function too. Is it because of the <head>? because I combined the <head> too.

Comment: `Is it because of the <head>? because I combined the <head> too` - huh? you didn't say you combined head ... you know a document can, like most humans, only have one head (certain states of America and Australia are exempted from this rule)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it without `type="text/javascript"` on last script tag. I don't know the logic behind it, but in some cases it has worked for me.

```
<script >
    $('.itemName').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select state',
        ajax: {
            url: '/select2-autocomplete-ajax',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.name,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution! I've figured out the problem.. So, the problem is because I need to remove some unnecessary headers.